# javascript engine: variable existance

Tags: javascript, scope

Consider the following code:

```
function foo(a)
{
   console.log(a+b);
}
foo(2);
```

will result in a **reference error** because b is not defined.

Now consider this:

```
function foo(a)
{
   console.log(a+b);
   var b = 0;
}
foo(2);
```

Here the result is **NaN**. So javascript knows `b` exists but it doesn't have a value yet.

The question: how can this be explained from a JS engine point of view? Simply put, it looks like the JS engine first declares all the variables in a scope, but only assigns values to it when needed. Does someone have a more scientific article on this?

I clearly understand what happens, I just want to know the reasoning behind it (why does the engine know `b` before using it)

Comment: It's called [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function foo(a)
{
   console.log(a+b);
   var b = 0;
}
```

Is actually seen like the following by JavaScript:

```
function foo(a)
{
   var b;
   console.log(a+b);
   b = 0;
}
```

This is called variable [*Hoisting*](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), when you declare a variable in JavaScript the declaration is hoisted to the top of declaring function and the assignment takes place in the original location.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed :). Will accept as soon as the system lets me

Comment: @PoeHaH You are welcome, glad I could help. You can ream more about this in the link I posted.